# GO action after a submit (go URI)

Tags: orbeon

We have the go button enabled but somehow we haven't been able to make this work properly.

This is the example instruction from the documentation:

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.submit.go.uri-xpath.*.*" value="/book/details/link"/>
```

We have tried static as well as dynamic uri values but without success.

We tried a URI like:

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.submit.go.uri-xpath.*.*" value="'http://www.google.com'"/>
```

and other dynamic ones, but, whatever we try we keep getting a dialogwindow saying the following:

===============================

An error has occured

You may want to try one of the following:

```
* Close this dialog and continue to use this page.
* Reload this page. Note that you will lose any unsaved changes.
* If the above does not work, try reloading the page yourself. Note that you will lose any unsaved changes:
      o With Firefox: hold down the shift key and click the Reload button in your browser toolbar.
      o With Safari and Chrome: click the Reload button in your browser toolbar.
      o With Internet Explorer: hold down the control key and click the Reload button in your browser toolbar.
* Return home.
```

Show Details Show details

===============================

What do we do wrong? Can you give some examples what values to use?

BTW We use the stable build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't aware of this issue with the 3.8 release (from almost 9 months ago), but I can indeed reproduce it, and confirm this issue has been fixed since then. So I recommend that you get a [night build](http://www.orbeon.com/forms/download) for now. We are close to releasing 3.9, so nightly builds should be fairly stable, and I wouldn't be worried about using one, at least for development.